# Why Ubuntu/Gnome/Nautinus masked Xf86launchA and Xf86launchB without doing anything?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, shortcut-keys

I need XF86LaunchB or XF86LaunchA for Guake, and it's annoying that they do not work in Gnome desktop or Nautilus. Something 's wrong with Ubuntu or Gnome. They masked those shortcut without doing anything.

Please help me remove these masks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: When you say "mask", what do you mean exactly? If it's a technical term, I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @wjandrea ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @wjandrea 'mask' mean that the shortcut key does not work in Nautilus while it work in other app, like Firefox .etc